# Looping through values in_array and checking multiple checkboxes using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have a series of `Grades` that are contained within a loop. I want to check if a database-driven (looped) checkbox's value matches with any of the values in the loop. If it does match a given item, then mark that input item as 'checked.'

For example, `print_r($grades_array)` outputs the following data:

```
Array ( [0] => Grade 5 [1] => Grade 8 [2] => Grade 9 )
```

And here's my loop through each of the input items (I'm using Laravel and Semantic UI, but the PHP concepts should still be the same):

```
@foreach($list_of_grades as $output_grade)
  <div class="inline field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="grade"
        @if(in_array($output_grade->name, $grade_array))
          checked="checked"
        @endif
        tabindex="0" class="hidden">
      <label>{{ $output_grade->name }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Here's what I am getting as output:

[image: HTML output (actual)]

However, this is what I would expect to get as output:

[image: Desired HTML output]

**Any ideas as to what's wrong with the code?**

And, just to clarify before it's asked, yes, the `$output_grade->name` values and the values within the array match. I can swap for ID as well and it produces the same single checked value result.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this: https://eval.in/931520. Please provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: This might work (trying to pull data from Laravel into the example; let me know if this doesn't make sense) https://eval.in/931536

Comment: Although that is outputting 'checked' correctly. Must be something else going on...

Answer (score 0):

**I face same case, Use just a trick if you find better solution please knock me**

```
@php
    $arrayValue = explode(',', $grade_array);
@endphp

@foreach($arrayValue as $data)
   @php $arrayData[$data] = $data @endphp
@endforeach

@foreach($list_of_grades as $output_grade)
  <div class="inline field">
    <div class="ui checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" name="grade"
        @if(in_array($output_grade->name, $arrayData))
          checked="checked"
        @endif
        tabindex="0" class="hidden">
      <label>{{ $output_grade->name }}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

But it working for me tested

[here screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKLAE.png)